# Символы в таблице MySQL

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица в базе данных. Почему во время вставки значений в таблицу MySQL исключаются символы "№" и "§"? Как разрешить сохранять их в таблице?

---

[image: Сохранение символа "№"]
[image: Результат]

Comment: Какой у вас набор символов в таблице?

Comment: Как понять набор символов?)

Comment: Такая же проблема.
Нужно ждать ответ...

Comment: То есть UTF-8 или Windows-1251 или ANSI или...?

Comment: На самой базе UTF-8.

Comment: @Lesperanza, а у таблицы или у данного поля *charset* не переопределён?

Comment: @alexander barakin, cp866_general_ci. Выбрал именно эту, потому что понимает русский язык. Остальные его крючками и символами сохраняют в таблице.

Comment: вот и поменяйте на *utf8* (если данных в таблице пока нет).

Comment: @Lesperanza, *крючками и символами* — унифицируйте всё под *utf8* и проблем не будет: 1. у всей базы (таблицы наследуют от базы, поля наследуют от таблицы, если специально не переопределять). 2. у всех программ, которые к базе обращаются (включая *phpmyadmin*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

для того, чтобы не возникало подобных проблем, лучше унифицировать всё под один *charset* (ныне стандартом де-факто является *utf8*):

- базу данных
- таблицы (если не задано специально, то наследуют *charset* от базы данных)
- столбцы (если на задано специально, то наследуют *charset* от таблицы)
- все подключающиеся к базе данных программы (начиная с самой *субд* и заканчивая *phpmyadmin-ом*).