# Проблемы с кодировкой в MariaDb

Tags: mariadb

Решил установить MariaDB, но проблемы с кодировкой. Делаю простой Insert с русскими символами и получаю иероглифы. Как там изменить кодировку на utf-8 ?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433949/178576

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET character_set_server = 'utf8';
SET collation_server = 'utf8_unicode_ci';
```

или my.cnf:

```
[client]
...
default-character-set=utf8
...
[mysql]
...
default-character-set=utf8
...
[mysqld]
...
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
...
```

Comment: Я написал первый пункт- не работает что-то

Comment: Ну, вам нужно создать новую базу, так как старая по умолчанию создалась не в utf8. Изменение конфига потребует перегрузки сервера.

Comment: Спасибо. Заработало))